# Third party payment processing and granting user access upon payment completion

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I am using a PayPal to process payments on my website using a form similar to the one below. My websites is a service provider where in order for users to create an account, users must submit a payment, which gives them full access to the services the website provides. I was wondering if there is an easy way to assure that the payment has been processed using the form below prior to actually creating the user account and granting user access?

```
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@gmail.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="apples">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1701">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="119.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.000">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_SM.gif:NonHostedGuest">
                <input type="image" src="http://www.zaptel.com/zaptel/customer/zaptel/images/btn_checkout.gif" border="0" name="submit">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Paypal's IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://www.paypal.com/ipn/) to receive notice of payment and then update their account to grant them access to that content. Paypal offers [code samples](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623) to get you started.